# verify the central limit theorem of chi sq distribution

Tags: r, normality-assumption, central-limit-theorem

I have a question on verifying the central limit theorem using R.

the question was to use data generated from different statistical distribution n see if the sample means follow normal distribution .

iam starting with a sample of size rchisq(20, 20) 
and then increasing the number of my samples by 5 in each interval. ie. , 25, 30, 25, ... then i will using the KS test shapiro test available in R to test for their normality for each sample.

question is should i first define a population of 1000 first then take different samples of size 20 and then running my tests ? this is because i read the defnition that CLT takes different combination of sample size N from a population to create population of means.

Comment: (i) You can't 'detect normality' by such an approach. You can only detect  non-normality (or fail to detect it). Since means of chi-squares aren't exactly normal, if you take a large enough sample of $\bar{x}$'s, you'll always reject; thus failure to reject is merely an indication your sample size wasn't large enough! Non-rejection doesn't imply the null is true. (ii) showing that the standardized sample mean from a chi-square at some finite sample size is approximately normal doesn't really establish the CLT for the chi-square ...(ctd)

Comment: (ctd) ... (for example, it might be that it actually goes to something different from - but very, very close to - normal; how would you know?). Actual CLT's are about behaviour in the limit, not at some set of finite sample sizes.  You're investigating something about how quickly you're approaching normality at small sample sizes, a fascinating and important area, about which the CLT doesn't speak.  $\quad$ (iii) this is not really a code-review site. If you want, you could explain your algorithm in plain English, in more mathematical terms, or perhaps even use some pseudocode ... (ctd)

Comment: (ctd) ... and then your question could be more on-topic and also more useful to later readers with similar problems. If you're concerned about your general approach, describe that and ask about that. If you want a code review, there's a SE site for that (codereview). If you're concerned about bugs in your code, document the behaviour with a working example and submit to the site for that (stackoverflow). $\quad$ (iv) Please don't bug for help in comments. We *know* you want help, that's why you're posting.

Comment: the question was to "see whether the sample mean follow normal distribution" and to "use normality tests in R" to "test for normality using sample sizes from 20 to 50"  .. i got really really confused.

Comment: In respect of the first question, sample means from chi-square distributions are gamma-distributed (and so, never actually normal, though they get pretty close to it with means of large samples).  In respect of the second part, I don't see any point to that at all - we know they're not normal, so a formal hypothesis test is essentially useless (it doesn't tell us *how far from normal* they are, that's an effect-size question, not a hypothesis test question - failure to reject just means you didn't have a large enough sample of means to see the difference you already know to be there) ...(ctd)

Comment: (ctd) ... Why you're not instead asked investigate some form of measure of 'how far from normal it is' beats me. By the way, thanks for modifying your question.